# Converter data Json (2018-09-20 15:58:38) para (20/09/2018 15:58:38)

Tags: angular

Durante o desenvolvimento de um app no angular, recebo um json
com valores e data. Preciso exibir no lista-pagamento.html a data no formato
dd/mm/aaaa. De que forma posso fazer ?

**ListaPagamento.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../base.component'
import { Atividade } from '../../agenda/models/atividade';
import { CurrencyUtils } from '../../utils/currency-utils';

@Component({
    selector: 'lista-pagamento-cielo',
    templateUrl: './templates/lista-pagamento.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../dashboard/styles/dashboard.css'],
    providers: []
})

export class ListaPagamento extends BaseComponent {

     constructor() { super() }

     title = 'Tela Cancelamento Cielo';

     cliente = [
        {Holder:'TRTPE', ReceivedDate:'2018-09-20 16:22:51',Tid:'0920042251610',Amount:'90.00',PaymentId:'73626a76-7601-4902-a884-bab3d1b4cc8e'},
        {Holder:'BC Advogados', **ReceivedDate:'2018-09-20 15:58:38**',Tid:'0920040857659',Amount:'90,00',PaymentId:'cb052369-0fcc-45d3-b35c-39d2829a9d7b'},
        {Holder:'OABr', ReceivedDate:'2018-09-20 16:22:33',Tid:'0920042251610',Amount:'90',PaymentId:'8327b48d-fcf8-4088-8418-79388ac8dfc3'}

     ];
}
```

**lista-pagamento.html**

```
<div class="portlet  portlet-fit white" [ngBusy]="busy">
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <!-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
                <span style="border-left:1px solid #eee;margin-left:2px;"> &nbsp;</span>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <span> <b>{{title}}</b></span>


        <div class="table-scrollable">
            <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="listaComprasCielo" role="grid" style="width:100%;">
                <thead class="">
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>TID</th>
                        <th>Valor da venda </th>
                        <th>Acao</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr role="row"  *ngFor="let clientes of cliente">
                        <!-- NPU / CIV -->
                        <td>{{clientes.Holder}}</td>
                        <td>{{clientes.ReceivedDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{clientes.Tid}}</td>
                        <td>{{clientes.Amount}}</td>
                        <td>
                          <!-- Acao -->
                          <button>Cancelar Cielo</button>
                        </td>
                        <!-- CLIENTE(HOLDING) -->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Imagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que o [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) irá lhe ajudar nisso. Todos os `problemas` que eu tive com formatação, conversão e afins, consegui resolver com ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o filter date

```
<td>{{clientes.ReceivedDate | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
<td>{{clientes.Amount | currency:"R$" }}</td>
```

**AngularJS**
[Referência Filter Date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date#usage) |
[Referência Filter Currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

**Angular** [Referência DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) | [Referência CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

> **Edit:**
>   Embora as tags indicassem se tratar de AngularJS e a solução funcionar no Angular também adicionei as referências paras as duas plataformas.

Comment: É possível formato Amount:'90' na saída no html para 90.00 R$

Comment: no caso seria com o currency

Comment: Eu recebo do json 9000 cujo valor é igual 90.00 R$ porém no formato estabelecido pelo angular fica currency fica 9.000 R$

Comment: Divida por 100...